# margin: 0 auto does not appear to center

Tags: css, html, margin, centering

I understand that this question must have been asked many times before, but I have indeed looked at the already existing answers and nothing seems to work! I have defined width on the element, tried removing float:left (this doesn't seem to center it and it also breaks my layout..), tried setting it as display:block, I did before use a footer to clear the floats and all that, tried using text-align center as well. But yeah, nothing seems to center it.

```
.container3col {
    width: 1200px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
}

.leftbar {
    width: 180px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background:#00FF00;
    float:left;
    }
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 840px;
    background:#FF0000;
    float:left;
}
.rightbar {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background:#00F;
    float:left;
}
```

My HTML part does contain a lot of content currently so it might be a bit messy to post it all. Basically I created a container DIV and put the leftbar, content and rightbar DIVs inside it. I'm fairly sure all of the content fits within the width constraints of its DIV.

One thing that may affect my code is that I did use a script to change content from display:none; to display:block (so that the user can click on a link and load the rest of an article).

I made a two column layout before that seems to work perfectly; it centers just fine without needing to remove floats or anything like that. The display:none to block thing as I mentioned in the paragraph above is also used. The two column pages work perfectly fine.

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's a fiddle of it. Since lots of the content was unnecessary (i.e. articles just full of filler text), I removed some of it. http://jsfiddle.net/Snail489/W6C9v/6/

Comment: Show the relevant HTML. One thing I can say, `container3col` will only be centered if the window it's in is wider than 1200 pixels. Is that when the problem occurs? Anyway, using JS to change the display property shouldn't be a problem (unless there were typos in the JS, but let's assume not).

Comment: @avrahamcool Posted a fiddle of the problem. I did remove some of the unnecessary elements such as filler text for the articles.

Comment: @MrLister The window is wider than 1200px, yes (it's maximised in a res of 1366x780 or something similar - I don't remember exactly but I'm absolutely sure it's greater than 1200). When I created a similar two-column layout, the container was 1200 pixels and it did center perfectly in a maximised window.

Comment: You have an error in your CSS (HTML-type comment) that prevent the style for `.container3col` to be applied. Remove it.

Comment: @MrLister Didn't expect those comments to actually affect the layout, but looks like it did - the DIVs are centered now. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

instead of `margin: 0 auto;` try `text-align:center`

Comment: Tried text-align:center before. I presume I add to the container's styles; when I tried this nothing happens at all. If I try applying it to each div's style, the only thing that happens is the text being centered (and not the DIV itself).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<style>
/* CSS Document */
body {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000000;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }
.container3col 
    {
     width: 1200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display:block;
    }

.leftbar {
    width: 180px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background:#5F5;
    float:left;
}

.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 840px;
    background:#F55;
    float:left;
}

.rightbar {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background:#5FF;
    float:left;
}

.header {
    width:1200px;
    background:url(../texture.jpg);
}

.footer {
    background: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    background:url(../texture.jpg);
}
</style>
```

Check my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pB2aC/